# Nested model/view architecture

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, delegates

Qt/Qml uses model/view architecture [Model/View Programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) [Model/View Tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/modelview.html) but their examples are too simple. I want to know how it should look with more complex problem. Assume that we have Application. According to Qt's model/view architecture the best solution is to create ApplicationModel, ApplicationView and ApplicationDelegate. Now lets our Application to have a Console and other components. Console should be separated to ConsoleModel, ConsoleView and ConsoleDelegate. But Console has its own Input and Output, that should be separated to ConsoleOutputModel, ConsoleOutputView, ConsoleOutputDelegate and ConsoleInputModel, ConsoleInputView, ConsoleInputDelegate.
But how does it all should be combine? Should ApplicationModel contains ConsoleModel that contains ConsoleOutputModel and ConsoleInputModel? It makes sense, but what about views and delegates? Similarly or ApplicationDelegate should control ConsoleView and ConsoleDelegate? How then ConsoleOutputModel should be accesed by ConsoleOutputView?
I would be very grateful for every hint or example solution.

Comment: In my view every application is a tree of components. So the question is: Is Qt's model/view architecture define how to handle with such complex structure? If so, how? If not, just say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you imply is mostly incorrect. There's no reason to nest models, unless you wish to logically combine their data - and if so, you'd need to write a custom proxy model to do so. Existing proxy models provided by Qt have only one source model. This is just what's there, doing a multi-source proxy is certainly possible.

In Qt's model-view model, a delegate has a specific meaning: it is the visual "skin" used to interact with the item. It specifically derives from the the `QAbstractItemDelegate` class. The delegate concept applies to the viewed items from the model, not to the view as a whole. You may need many delegates, not just one, or no delegates at all. It's not the same as the delegate concept from model-view-controller.

Another issue I see is with demanding that the entire application is an `ApplicationView`. Qt doesn't provide views that would construct a widget-based user interface of the entire application using the `QAbstractItemModel` as a data source. The closest you get is `QUiLoader` which can load an `.ui` XML file and instantiate the UI objects - but that does not use the model-view framework, and is a one-time action: any changes to the underlying XML model are not propagated automatically.

The way models and views are typically used in Qt is to couple a model to one or more view widgets. Those widgets then show some subset of the model (perhaps the full model) in a particular way. You can even couple a model to any widget's property using the `QModelWidgetMapper`.

Comment: It is bad to feed such questions to show that they are welcome...

Comment: Well, there is a way to more-or-less objectively answer it. As you see, the answer mostly has to do with what's available in Qt and how it's used. It's not very general in that sense.